# How to default a generic extended return type

Tags: typescript-generics

I have faced the "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" problem a few times recently when trying to have a function that creates a basic implementation, but provides an ability to pass in a base value to spread over or some kind of constructor function:

```
type Animal = { readonly name: string };
const createDefaultAnimal = (): Animal => ({ name: 'default animal' });

export const createGenericAnimal: <T extends Animal>(
  createAnimal?: () => T
) => T = (createAnimal) => {
  return createAnimal ? createAnimal() : createDefaultAnimal();
};
```

Error:

> Type '(createAnimal: (() => T) | undefined) => Animal' is not assignable to type '(createAnimal?: (() => T) | undefined) => T'.
> Type 'Animal' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'Animal' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.ts(2322)

T can only ever bee the same type as the createAnimal return type or the default type, it seems that typescript is widening the types somewhere and getting confused.

I have tried with optional types, but they seems to have the same issue. Is there another way to achieve this?